# Erlang: How do you reload an application env configuration?

Tags: version-control, configuration, erlang

How do you reload an application's configuration? Or, what are good strategies for managing dynamic application configuration?

For example, let's say I had log levels and I wanted to change them at runtime. Also, let's assume this is one of many such options. Does it make sense to have a "configuration server" that holds configuration state for other parts of the application to query? Do people do that or did I just make it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's reasonable to keep all your configuration data in a repository (subversion, mercurial etc.) and have applications download it every time they start or attempt to reload <s>some</s> their configuration options. This is centralized approach — however you could have many configuration servers to avoid [SPOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) — and it:

- allows you to keep track of changes so that you
  know who put these and when (s)he did
  that (none wants to be in charge of 
  unproper configuration);
- enables you to use the same configuration for
  all applications throughout you
  network;
- easiness of changes: you can just modify 
  configuration and notify concerned applications 
  using `gen_server:abcast` call or other means.

`proplists(3)` are useful when reading configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, the problem is the following:

**You want to create a distributed, scalable system and of course Erlang is the first choice that comes into mind, since it was designed for such purposes.**

- You will have several nodes that will be running local applications and also distributed applications as well.
- Here the simplest hierarchy is to have a hot-standby backup for every major functionality.
- This can be achieved by implementing a distributed application controller.

  - Simplest example is to have a server start on a node, while a slave server is started simultaneously on a mate node.
  - Distributed Application controllers have many advantages.

    - Easy example is to handle node_up messages differently by introducing new messages that indicate that a node is not only erlang VM ready, but all vital applications are running. This way the mate node can be sure that the stand-by node is ready and can start sync-ing.

Please elaborate or comment if I misunderstood something.
Good luck!